# Use static properties for constants with java

Tags: java, static

In my java program I use a Constants.java class. In this class I created about 50 Strings properties in this way

```
public static final String startError = "The program could not be started, please ......";

    public static final String logPath="/Users/hgvu/";
```

In my program I use this class in this way for example

```
System.out.println(Constants.startError);
```

I am new in the domain, do you think it's a good idea to make fields in the Constants class static ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your class final, like `public final class Constants`. And Java doesn't let you create top-level static classes, I think you meant making fields static when you asked "do you think it's a good idea to make the Constants class static". The answer is yes, it is the best way to go about it.

Comment: yes sorry a meant all the fields are static. After making the classe final shall I leave the fields public static final ?

Comment: Yes, you shall exactly do that.

Comment: ok thank you. I have one other class called Validator which has only different boolean functions and used by other classes to check if request are valid. Shall also set it as public final and the functions to public static final ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion Constants should not vary - therefore they should always be static... This also means you can access the constant variable values without having to initiate the Constants.java class

Answer (score 0):

you wont be able to define a Static class in java **unless it is nested**, but if you want the constants to be shared across, then making it a nested class does not make any buyout.

But you can make your class **final** and have **private constructor** would be a good choice if you want this class to only contain your constants